# How to set up a trigger across databaes in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have got an "A" DATABASE and "B" DATABASE. When I inserted new record to "X TABLE" in "A" DATABASE I want to insert another record to "X2 Table" in "B" DATABASE with Trigger Function of SQL Server 2005.

How can I do this? How can I connect another Database and insert record specific table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete, working example.

### Code

```
USE master
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'A')
    DROP DATABASE A
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'B')
    DROP DATABASE B
GO
CREATE DATABASE A
GO
CREATE DATABASE B
GO
USE A
GO
CREATE TABLE X (Col1 varchar(10) NOT NULL)
GO
USE B
GO
CREATE TABLE X2 (Col1 varchar(10) NOT NULL)
GO
USE A
GO
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trX_Insert
ON dbo.X
FOR INSERT
AS BEGIN
    INSERT INTO B.dbo.X2 (Col1)
    SELECT Col1
    FROM Inserted
END
GO
INSERT INTO A.dbo.X (Col1) VALUES ('This')
INSERT INTO A.dbo.X (Col1) VALUES ('That')
GO
SELECT * FROM A.dbo.X
SELECT * FROM B.dbo.X2
GO
```

### Result

```
Col1
----------
This
That

Col1
----------
This
That
```

Comment: And rememeber to check that all users have enough access rights to both databases.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem that you will have is in qualifying the name of the new database. Otherwise, it's like a trigger writing to the same database. Here is an example of the T-SQL portion:

```
INSERT INTO b.dbo.X2
SELECT * FROM Inserted
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if it's doable in triggers, but in stored procedures you would write

```
INSERT INTO DBNAME.SCHEMA.TABLENAME(...)
VALUES(...
```

So, probably something like

```
INSERT INTO B.dbo.X2(...
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the database in the same sql server instance? if so, you can interact with tables in a neighboring database using <database name>.<schema name>.<table name>. If the database is in a separate instance, you would have to create a Linked Server and access through that.